# Exception when authenticating with wrong verification code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using *Firebase Phone Authentification* to verify users accounts. When I try to authenticate with a wrong verification code, I get an IllegalArgumentException. Is there any way to fix that without using `try` `catch` blocks?

Here is the exception message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, or temporaryProof.
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.example.myApp.testFragment$3$4.onClick(testFragment.java:316)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

And here is the line where I get the error :

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCode, inputCode);
```

I'm intentionally using wrong verification code in  `inputCode` and hoping to get an error message instead of the exception.

Comment: Check this official documentation for more info, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calls to [`PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.html#getCredential) return a [PhoneAuthCredential object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthCredential), which is defined as:

> Wraps phone number and verification information for authentication purposes.

So `getCredential()` cannot return an error message. Instead it throws an exception if there is a problem with the verification/credential information you provided.

Answer (score 7):

It returns an exception so the aim should be to catch the exception it throws in the debug console. I do that by wrapping the portion of that code in a try catch and Toast it out for the user of the aim to see rather than the usual crash which isnt visible to the End Users.

Like this...

```
private void verifyCode(String code) {
    try {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithCredential(credential);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Verification Code is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, After adding the try-catch block, the application is not crashing. But is it okay to design the application without resolving this exception(and just handling it in the try-catch block)?

Comment: No please its not okay to do so, the app crashes because of a wrong verification code entered in the program. So when we try catch, we prevent it from crashing and we can debug log the actual reason why it crashed while we show something nice to the end user rather than the message "app has stopped" and the app quits. Hope you get it now?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue and resolved it. actually you need to check verificationId and code is not null

Thanks.

Comment: This is correct. If either verificationId or the code is null/empty then this can throw an exception. For example, if a user just taps the button to confirm the code without entering a code the exception can be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, just add the SHA certificates. Error will dissolved.