# Getting an error in PhoneAuthCredential

Tags: android, firebase

what is the meaning of error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118488/exception-when-authentification-with-wrong-verification-code

Comment: it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

It returns an exception so the aim should be to catch the exception it throws in the debug console. I do that by wrapping the portion of that code in a try catch and Toast it out for the user of the aim to see rather than the usual crash which isnt visible to the End Users.

Like this...

```
private void verifyCode(String code) {
    try {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithCredential(credential);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verification Code is wrong, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calls to PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(...) return a PhoneAuthCredential object, which is defined as:

> Wraps phone number and verification information for authentication purposes.

So getCredential() cannot return an error message. Instead it throws an exception if there is a problem with the verification/credential information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your SHA1 key to your firebase app settings.