# firebase realtime database is not storing data and the logcat shows no error

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I am learning java and trying to register user's info in firebase realtime database when they register in the app ,but the data doesn't get stored in the database and the logcat shows no error so I can't figure out what's the problem.

P.S. - App is connected to the database &  firebase database rules are:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}
```

here's the SignUp.java file code

```
package com.example.foodapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variables
    private TextInputLayout regName,regUsername,regEmail,regPhoneNo,regPassword;
    private Button regBtn,regToLogInBtn;

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        //hooks
        regName = (TextInputLayout )findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        regUsername = (TextInputLayout )findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        regEmail = (TextInputLayout )findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        regPhoneNo = (TextInputLayout )findViewById(R.id.reg_phoneNo);
        regPassword = (TextInputLayout )findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        regBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
        regToLogInBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_login_btn);

        //save data in firebase using button click
        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                reference = rootNode.getReference("users");

                Log.d("HELLO", "Register Button Clicked");

                //get all value from text fields
               String name = regName.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String username = regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String email = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String phoneNo = regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();


                UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(name, username, email, phoneNo, password);

               

                reference.child(phoneNo).push().setValue(helperClass);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

the xml codes are:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignUp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:transitionName="logo_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:transitionName="logo_text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SignUp to start your new Journey"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:transitionName="logo_desc"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_name"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/reg_username"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        android:hint="Username"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:transitionName="username_tran">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:hint="Email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        //-----------------------------------------------------------

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_phoneNo"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        //---------------------------------------------------------

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:transitionName="password_tran">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:text="GO"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:transitionName="button_tran" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_login_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="Already have an account? Login"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:transitionName="login_signup_tran" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

```
the database is:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlaDs.png
````

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Do you have public getters in `UserHelperClass` ?

Comment: yes... i have used public in getters and setters @p2pdops

Comment: @AlexMamo ... I have not tried complete listener... But I have tried .. try catch block to see the error in Toast.... BUT it shows no error...

Comment: No, try to attach a listener and check if the task is not successful. Do get something printed in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have attached a completeListener with setvalue() with a msg in it....but it is not displaying in the logcat..!

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered? What is your database location?

Comment: @AlexMamo Database location: United States (us-central1)

Comment: reference.child(phoneNo).setValue(helperClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d("HELLO", "Register Button Clicked");
                //System.out.println("completed");
            }
        });

Comment: No, you should check if the task is not successful, log the error message. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo nothing is getting printed in the log cat..

Comment: ` reference.setValue(helperClass, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
                if (error != null) {
                    System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + error.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                }
            }
        }); `

Comment: Not like that. Add a complete lister directly to the .setValue() method, and check task.getException().getMessage(), right?

Comment: reference.child(phoneNo).setValue(helperClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    task.getException().getMessage();
                    //Log.e("Signup Error", "onCancelled", task.getException());
                } else {
                    Log.d("HELLO", "Register Button Clicked");
                }
            }
        });

Comment: @AlexMamo is this the right way??..

Comment: Yes, it is. What's the output?

Comment: @AlexMamo W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 34530138 , only wrote 34377840

Comment: That's a warning, I was talking about errros.

Comment: @AlexMamo there are no errors in logcat

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have no idea....how to check whether it is triggerd or not..

Comment: Add a Log statement and check that out.

Comment: @AlexMamo i had put statement..but nothing is printing......onComplte is not triggered

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on the user device?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes...it is connected to internet

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this question, after reading those answers, the reason of the issue is either you verification id or code is null or empty SHA certificates is not available on firebase app (console)

[Exception when authenticating with wrong verification code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118488/exception-when-authenticating-with-wrong-verification-code/62484685)